# multiple responses to new arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

Ok so i'm messing with arrays and right now i'm trying to get the second question that is answered to bring up a new message instead of "correct!" when it's found to be correct in this case i want it to reply "gerp" if correct for the second question. But i'm not entirely sure how to do it.  What am i messing up?

```
 var i = 0;

 var myArray = new Array({
   q: "What was her favorite Color?",
   a: "purple"
 }, {
   q: "gymhoaccetpptfe",
   a: "rev six nine eleven"
 });

 function myFunction() {
   var x;
   var name = prompt(myArray[i].q);
   if (name == myArray[i].a) {
     x = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + " " + "correct!";
     i = i + 1;
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
   } else if ((name == myArray[i + 1].a) {
     x = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + " " + "gerp!";
   } else {
     x = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + name + " " + "is" + " " + "wrong!";
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your error console (<kbd>F12</kbd>). You have a syntax error here:

```
else if ((name == myArray[i + 1].a)
{
...
```

You're missing an ending parenthesis. These errors (syntax errors) are more than often caught by the browser, so a simple check should fix it.

Also, the reason you're not getting the output "gerp!" is because you set a variable to the `innerHTML`, but you don't actually update the `innerHTML` of the element. So add this line to both the `else if` statement and the `else` statement.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

Comment: Always good advice to keep the console on while developing in Javascript.  It can save much wailing and gnashing of teeth.

Comment: While that's a syntax bug, that's not what's preventing 'gerp!' from appearing

Comment: Do you know where i could go to solve the problem?
Also thanks for pointing out the syntax error i would have totally missed that.

Comment: @TBW What do you mean? Are you still having trouble? With what?

Comment: "Gerp" Is still not showing up when question two is answered correctly. It still just says "correct"

Comment: @TBW It's because you forgot to set the innerHTML. I'll update my post.

Comment: hmm, now if you get the question wrong for question two there's no incorrect message and it still just says correct if you're correct.

Comment: @TBW I don't understand. It works for me -- http://jsfiddle.net/JCYxK/ It says `x is wrong` if I get both wrong. If I get question 1 right it says 'correct'. Or if I get that wrong but get ques 2 right it says "gerp".

Comment: @David i tried out your code and i got the same results as with my code. Could it be because i'm accessing the whole thing via an html file that uses the js file im having problems with via a button? If i re-word that: Could it be the method in which i am activating the code in my browser that is causing the problem?

Comment: @TBW Maybe but I'm not sure. You should reask the question and be more specific as to your problem. I'm sure you'll get help.

Comment: will do. Thanks for the help :) At least now i know the problem is probably somewhere else.